# php browser simpleTest login issue

Tags: php, simpletest

I am trying to login to a website using simpleTest browser.

Below is my code

```
require_once('simpletest/browser.php');

$browser = new SimpleBrowser();

$browser->get('http://uosom.dzxpy.servertrust.com/login.asp');
$browser->setField('email', 'asher@wds-testing.com');
$browser->setField('password', 'password123');
echo $browser->clickSubmitByName('imageField2');
```

It is not logging me in and even it does not throw an error.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you are correct. Do you have a solution? I can not rename or change input type.

Comment: thank you! I get it working by clickImageByName()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is beacuse the type of `imageField2` isn't `submit` but `image`. Function `ClickSubmitByName()` searches for inputs of type `submit` (Your input code is `<input type="image" border="0" name="imageField2" src="v/vspfiles/templates/240/images/buttons/btn_login.gif">`). You can use `ClickImageByName()` instead.